# Set the shape of a Variable to the batch size in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to initialize a Tensorflow variable, whose shape should be the same as a placeholder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
events = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name='events')
opt_res = tf.get_variable('opt_res', initializer=tf.truncated_normal(shape=tf.shape(events), mean=0.0, stddev=1e-1))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    sess.run([opt_res], feed_dict={'events:0': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
```

I get below error. The error is in the `tf.shape(events)`.

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("truncated_normal:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
```

The `events` variable is a vector whose length is equal to the batch size. The batch size is set to 2048. However, the last batch is usually less than 2048. So I have to set the shape to `[None]`.

In this case, how should I copy the shaple of `events` to `opt_res`?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to create variable. you can do it like this

```py
import tensorflow as tf
events = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name='events')
opt_res = tf.truncated_normal(shape=tf.shape(events), mean=0.0, stddev=1e-1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    val = sess.run([opt_res], feed_dict={events: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
    print(val)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually in my actual code, I try to learn opt_res through training. So I need it to be a variable.

Comment: In that case I think you want opt_res of batch size because during training you will change same training variable in all batch.

Comment: how should I do that? the batches do not always have the same size. The last batch often has a smaller size

Comment: may be you can pad your last batch with some aggregate value to make the same size. why do even need trainable variable and batch size be equal, do you have some operation between it? How will you use your model during prediction because during prediction any number of test data can be passed